# How to select consecutive rows from a multi-index pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index pandas dataframe (groupbydataframe) as below:

```
Store  Year  Month
1      2013  1         4922.0
             2         5315.5
             3         5603.0
             4         4625.0
             5         4995.0
             6         4407.0
             7         4421.0
             8         4494.0
             9         4212.0
             10        4148.5
             11        5033.5
             12        6111.0
       2014  1         4547.5
             2         4726.5
             3         4455.0
             4         4577.5
             5         4909.0
             6         4788.0
             7         4507.0
             8         4124.0
             9         3970.5
             10        4431.0
             11        5220.0
             12        6466.0
       2015  1         4690.0
             2         4467.5
             3         4294.5
             4         4256.0
             5         4529.0
             6         4102.0
                       ...   
1112   2013  2        10991.0
             3        12322.0
             4        10705.0
             5        12096.0
             6        11029.0
             7        10419.0
             8         8994.0
             9         9448.0
             10        9019.0
             11        9294.0
             12       11163.0
       2014  1         8156.5
             2         8862.5
             3         8606.5
             4         9662.0
             5        10375.0
             6         8755.0
             7         8262.0
             8         8454.0
             9         7621.5
             10        8779.0
             11        9638.0
             12        9592.0
       2015  1         9345.0
             2         8466.5
             3         8457.0
             4         8715.0
             5         9125.0
             6         8528.0
             7         7728.0
```

The last column is "Sales".

1. If `FindYear=2014` and `FindMonth=01` how do I extract  sales for `2013-12` to `2014-02` for `Store=1`?
2. if `FindYear` and `FindMonth` are lists with `length(FindYear)=length(Store)`. How do do (1) without looping through all stores individually?
3. Or am I looking at this the wrong way? do I need to `unstack()` and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert second and third level of `Multiindex` [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
s = pd.Series({(1, 2013, 2): 5315.5, (1, 2014, 8): 4124.0, (1, 2014, 9): 3970.5, (1112, 2013, 8): 8994.0, (1, 2013, 12): 6111.0, (1, 2015, 3): 4294.5, (1112, 2014, 10): 8779.0, (1, 2014, 10): 4431.0, (1112, 2013, 9): 9448.0, (1112, 2014, 12): 9592.0, (1, 2015, 2): 4467.5, (1, 2014, 11): 5220.0, (1112, 2013, 10): 9019.0, (1, 2015, 1): 4690.0, (1112, 2013, 11): 9294.0, (1112, 2015, 2): 8466.5, (1, 2013, 9): 4212.0, (1112, 2015, 1): 9345.0, (1112, 2013, 4): 10705.0, (1, 2013, 8): 4494.0, (1112, 2014, 9): 7621.5, (1112, 2013, 5): 12096.0, (1, 2014, 4): 4577.5, (1, 2013, 11): 5033.5, (1, 2015, 6): 4102.0, (1112, 2013, 6): 11029.0, (1, 2014, 5): 4909.0, (1, 2013, 10): 4148.5, (1, 2015, 5): 4529.0, (1112, 2014, 8): 8454.0, (1112, 2013, 7): 10419.0, (1, 2014, 6): 4788.0, (1, 2015, 4): 4256.0, (1, 2014, 7): 4507.0, (1112, 2014, 5): 10375.0, (1112, 2015, 3): 8457.0, (1112, 2014, 4): 9662.0, (1, 2013, 5): 4995.0, (1112, 2013, 2): 10991.0, (1, 2014, 1): 4547.5, (1112, 2014, 7): 8262.0, (1, 2013, 4): 4625.0, (1112, 2013, 3): 12322.0, (1, 2014, 2): 4726.5, (1112, 2014, 6): 8755.0, (1, 2013, 7): 4421.0, (1, 2014, 3): 4455.0, (1112, 2014, 1): 8156.5, (1, 2013, 6): 4407.0, (1112, 2014, 11): 9638.0, (1, 2014, 12): 6466.0, (1, 2013, 1): 4922.0, (1112, 2015, 7): 7728.0, (1112, 2013, 12): 11163.0, (1112, 2014, 3): 8606.5, (1112, 2015, 4): 8715.0, (1112, 2014, 2): 8862.5, (1, 2013, 3): 5603.0, (1112, 2015, 6): 8528.0, (1112, 2015, 5): 9125.0})
```

```
per = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index.map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x[1]) 
                                                          + str(x[2]), format='%Y%m')))
        .to_period('m')

print (per)
PeriodIndex(['2013-01', '2013-02', '2013-03', '2013-04', '2013-05', '2013-06',
             '2013-07', '2013-08', '2013-09', '2013-10', '2013-11', '2013-12',
             '2014-01', '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04', '2014-05', '2014-06',
             '2014-07', '2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-10', '2014-11', '2014-12',
             '2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-04', '2015-05', '2015-06',
             '2013-02', '2013-03', '2013-04', '2013-05', '2013-06', '2013-07',
             '2013-08', '2013-09', '2013-10', '2013-11', '2013-12', '2014-01',
             '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04', '2014-05', '2014-06', '2014-07',
             '2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-10', '2014-11', '2014-12', '2015-01',
             '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-04', '2015-05', '2015-06', '2015-07'],
            dtype='int64', freq='M')
```

Then assign new `Multiindex`, where second level is `PeriodIndex`:

```
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('Store'), per))
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = ('Store','Period'))
print (s)
Store  Period 
1      2013-01     4922.0
       2013-02     5315.5
       2013-03     5603.0
       2013-04     4625.0
       2013-05     4995.0
       2013-06     4407.0
       2013-07     4421.0
       2013-08     4494.0
       2013-09     4212.0
       2013-10     4148.5
       2013-11     5033.5
       2013-12     6111.0
       2014-01     4547.5
       2014-02     4726.5
       2014-03     4455.0
...
...
...
```

Selecting with `loc`:

```
print (s.loc[1,pd.Period('2014-01')])
4547.5

print (s.loc[1,pd.Period('2013-12'):pd.Period('2014-02')])
Store  Period 
1      2013-12    6111.0
       2014-01    4547.5
       2014-02    4726.5
Name: Sales, dtype: float64

per1 = pd.Period('2014-01')
per2 = pd.Period('2015-01')
per = [per1, per2]

print (s.loc[1, per1 - 1: per1 + 1])
Store  Period 
1      2013-12    6111.0
       2014-01    4547.5
       2014-02    4726.5
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Multiple selecting by list comprehension:

```
print ([s.loc[1, x - 1: x + 1] for x in per])
[Store  Period 
1      2013-12    6111.0
       2014-01    4547.5
       2014-02    4726.5
Name: Sales, dtype: float64, Store  Period 
1      2014-12    6466.0
       2015-01    4690.0
       2015-02    4467.5
Name: Sales, dtype: float64]
```

which can be concated:

```
print (pd.concat([s.loc[1, x - 1: x + 1] for x in per]))
Store  Period 
1      2013-12    6111.0
       2014-01    4547.5
       2014-02    4726.5
       2014-12    6466.0
       2015-01    4690.0
       2015-02    4467.5
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I did not think outside the box!! Converting "year" and "month" to "year-month" datetime index is the most straightforward way!

Comment: consider a multi-index dataframe with `Store` and `YearMonth` (e.g: `2014-01`) as `levels[0]` and `levels[1]` respectively. Is there a way to perform in-place conversion of `YearMonth` to `DatetimeIndex` with `freq='M'`

Comment: I think I have figured out how to do it inplace.  `s.index.set_levels(per, level='YearMonth', inplace=True)`  but haven't tested it properly. However this still uses `per` which is separate sequence to force levels to new.

Comment: There is another possible solution - convert `MultiIndex` to columns, then create new period column and delete unnecessary columns. Then set index with period column. But it seems for me less effective.

Comment: when i try `print (s.loc[1, per1 - 1: per1 + 1])`, I get `invalid syntax` on `colon (:)` operator. I am using anaconda 3.5 python ?  If I `print(per1-1)` and `print(per1+1)` it looks fine, but somehow it complains when I try with `:` operator

Comment: Hmmm, and this works nice? `print (s.loc[1,pd.Period('2013-12'):pd.Period('2014-02')])`

Comment: What is `s.index` ?

Comment: `print(pd.Period('2013-12'):pd.Period('2014:02'))` also produces `syntax error` on `:` operator. So I doubt dataframe `s` is the problem. Moreover, I have tried a single period with `loc` and it works fine. Its just that when ':' operator is used it throws an error

Comment: Maybe problem is I use `s =df.Sales`

Comment: I add series sample to answer.

Comment: right!  `s` is a Series not a dataframe in your example. On the otherhand, after you `multi-index` isn't the resulting output a multiindex dataframe or is there such thing as multiindex series? But that still does not explain why `print(pd.Period('2013-12'):pd.Period('2014:02'))` throws a syntax error?

Comment: Hmmm, I think if some dataframe has multiindex, then it contains series with multiindex (each column is series). So I think you can simple rewrite your code - where is `s` use column like `df.Sales`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120075/discussion-between-user2979010-and-jezrael).